# Problem selecting element with jQuery

Tags: jquery

This code makes one comment box:

```
<div class="com_box">
  <div class="com_box">
    <div class="com_box_text"> text </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="com_box_info">
  <img ... />
  <div> ... </div>
  <div>
    <a href="" id="quote"> text </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

When i click a#quote i want to do something with the div.com_box_text over. How do i select it with jQuery?

Comment: For clarification, will the code you show here appear more than one time on the page?  Is this an example of a repeated list of comments?  I ask because if a#quote appears more than 1 time on the page you will get funky jQuery results because you all id attributes on the page must be unique.  (I apologize if I am barking up the wrong tree).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#quote").click(function() {
        $(".com_box_tex").html("foo");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#quote").click(
    function(){
        var info_box = $(this).closest(".com_box_text");
        // do stuff with info_box
    }
);
```

Edit: I'm assuming you mean you wanted to do something with the nearest instance of that class, not with all elements of that class.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#qoute").click(function(
       $(".com_box_text").hide(); //or something else ;)
    ));
});
```